# Testing a property of a React HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I've got a HOC like this:

```
const myHoc = ComposedComponent => class Hoccomp extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.foo = 'bar';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ComposedComponent {...this.props}/>
    );
  }
};
```

How do I run a test to determine that `this.foo === 'bar'`?
I'm currently using `react-addons-test-utils` but I'm open to any solution, as long as I can run it in a node environment.

Answer (score 0):

Components are functions and classes. You could simply instantiate one and call the method and then check the instance.

However, if you shallow render, you can call `getMountedInstance()` to get access to the created component and test it that way. For example:

```js
var shallowRenderer = ReactTestUtils.createRenderer();
shallowRenderer.render( <myHoc /> );
expect( shallowRenderer.getMountedInstance().foo ).toEqual( 'bar' );
```

---

However, ensure two things: (1) that you are not just testing internal implementation details, which is to say that you are testing what is *exposed*; and (2) that you are really sure setting a variable on `this` is what you want, as opposed to passing in props, which allows your composed components to be pure and stateless. As an example of the latter:

```
const Bare = ({ bar }) => (
  <h1>
    foo = {bar}
  </h1>
);

const Hoc = Component => class Hoc extends Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    this.foo = 'bar';
  }

  render () {
    return ( <Component {...this.props} foo={this.foo} /> );
  }
}

// use the hoc
const Wrapped = Hoc( Bare );
ReactDOM.render( <Wrapped />, document.getElementById( 'app' ) );
```

This is cleaner and easier to test - for both components. And testing `this.foo` wouldn't make a lot of sense because we'd be wanting to test that `foo` was passed as a prop - the internal implementation is irrelevant to a good unit test.

All that said, there are cases where you'd want to test assigned properties. Just be sure it's what you want in this case.

Comment: I don't understand how your example renders a HOC without a component given. I get this `Shallow rendering works only with custom components, not primitives (Hoc). Instead of calling `.render(el)` and inspecting the rendered output, look at `el.props` directly instead.`

Comment: You can't render a HOC without a component given, in most cases, because what would it render? But the component given can be anything, including a pure component function (e.g.  `const comp = () => (<p>Test</p>);`). You could design a HOC to avoid that, if necessary. I can amend if you want an example of that.